# rescue for a rotting euphorbia

Tags: rot, euphorbia

would like to save as much of the main trunk as possible, i already cut off about 12 various sized branches from the base ....

this is where i’m considering to stop. does it look healthy enough?

thanks so much,
a guilty feeling plant mama

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cuttings look fine to me, no black rot or soft spots are good indicators.

If you want to root the cuttings I would consider removing some of the smaller branches.  Just cut them cleanly with a knife.  Smaller sections are often easier to root and newer growth often roots faster.

For all the sections just put them to one side in a sunny area for a few days so they form a callous at the cut area.  No rush whether it's a few days or a week!

Then pot them up in individual pots in a free draining mixture.  I have used sharp sand or chicken grit or "cactus soil" (which is just peat and perlite).  Keep the mix damp not wet!

Large cuttings are a problem to keep upright as they are top heavy.  Don't be afraid to provide some support with stakes.  Check the cuttings after a few months by taking one out of the sand/mix/... and confirming the root growth.

Repot into a clay pot with free draining soil in high sun and water sparingly.

Comment: thank you for such a detailed help! so, after 5 days i wanted to pot them, but a couple of the cuttings and the main trunk got mushy next where the cut was made (added a photo above). pot them anyway, or cut more, wait for callous then do it?

Comment: @cumica yes, the cut area needs to dry out and callous,  wait a week even ten days unless they are in really high sun